# What is the Permutation Matrix in FFT DFT Factorization?

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Given: 
$$F_N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&\cdots &1 \\
1&\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\cdots&\omega^{N-1} \\
1&\omega^2&\omega^4&\omega^6&\cdots&\omega^{2(N-1)}\\ 1&\omega^3&\omega^6&\omega^9&\cdots&\omega^{3(N-1)}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&\omega^{N-1}&\omega^{2(N-1)}&\omega^{3(N-1)}&\cdots&\omega^{(N-1)(N-1)}\\
\end{bmatrix}, $$

[image]

where $D = $ diag($1,\omega,\omega^2,...,\omega^N$).  We note that $\omega^N = 1$, so $\omega^{N/2} = -1 $.

What is meant by odd-even permutation in this context?

Available notes on FFT online are generally highly condensed, thus they are very difficult to decipher.  Using $F_4$ as a template, i've found that permutation matrices $P$ such that $P F$ is row sorted into odd powers of $\omega$ and then even powers of $\omega$, and visa versa, don't ostensibly work.

I additionally am not sure how you can convert the consecutive $F_{N/2}$ matrices on the top of the second matrix into rows that span to all necessary powers of $\omega$.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs5220-s10/slides/fft.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

To see this thing "at work" and illustrate Florian's answer (+1), let me put in English what the $1$'s in each row are doing, perhaps by focusing on the first (in red), second (also in red) and fifth rows (in blue):

$$\bf P=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\color{red}1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&\color{red}1&0\\
0&\color{blue}1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&\color{blue}1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\color{blue}1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\color{blue}1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Say we multiply $\bf{Px},$ where $\bf x$ is a vector simply enumerating the integers $0,1,2,3,\dots,7,$ i.e. $\small\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\end{bmatrix}^\top$ - in this case each integer representing the vector element order - then we can see that the first operation (in the typical mechanics of matrix multiplication) will be dotting the first row in the matrix $\bf P,$ i.e. $\small\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ with the vector $\bf x,$ which will select the first element (even) in the vector, i.e. $0.$ The next operation will dot the second row of the matrix $\bf P$ with the vector $\bf x,$ selecting its third element (even), i.e. $2.$ And so forth and so on, until we get to the fifth row, $\small\begin{bmatrix}0&\color{blue}1&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$ which will start off the process of selecting the second element (odd) of the matrix, i.e. $1.$

Here it is:

```
> p = matrix(c(         1,rep(0,7),
+              rep(0,2),1,rep(0,5),
+              rep(0,4),1,rep(0,3),
+              rep(0,6),1,rep(0,1),
+              rep(0,1),1,rep(0,6),
+              rep(0,3),1,rep(0,4),
+              rep(0,5),1,rep(0,2),
+              rep(0,7),1          ),8,8,1)
> (v = c(0:7))
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7       # Vector [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
> as.vector(t(p %*% v))
[1] 0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7       # Vector [0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7] even / odd separated.
```

So in the case of $\bf {F}_{64},$ for example, multiplying the signal in the original domain in a vector $\bf x,$ the $64^2$ elementary multiplications can reduced to $2\times 32^2$ by making the matrix sparse:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\bf F_{64}\end{bmatrix}=\color{gray}{\begin{bmatrix}\bf I& \bf D\\\bf I&\bf {-D}\end{bmatrix}}\begin{bmatrix}\bf F_{32}&0\\0&\bf F_{32}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\bf P_{64}\end{bmatrix}$$

with

$$\small \bf D =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0 &w&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&w^2&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0&w^3&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0&0&w^4&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&w^{31}
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is explained [here](https://youtu.be/M0Sa8fLOajA?t=2097) by Professor Strang.

Answer (score 1):

Some references:

the videos of Gilbert Strang (MIT, around 1999) on this subject.

https://math.berkeley.edu/~berlek/classes/CLASS.110/LECTURES/FFT

https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gilbert/REU/REUNewApp2Sum06.pdf

More far reaching:

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs5220-s10/slides/fft.pdf

etc.

Comment: Of the links, I like this one:  http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs5220-s10/slides/fft.pdf .

However, it seems that to make $F_8$ work (in slide 12) I have to take the transpose of the matrix product and then subject it to an appropriate permutation matrix.  In effect, I don't think that penalizes the operation count, but it doesn't seem indicated by the slides.

Comment: I have a working model of $F_4$ (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A6eBcTHlEL4/maxresdefault.jpg) already, but my attempted generalization to $F_8$, meant to ensure I mastered the pattern in order to tackle the general case, failed.  A working model of $F_8$ should be enough to finish the derivation - though of different form than that in my initial question.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The permutation matrix P for FFT of $F_8$ is
$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Without a more substantive explanation, Readers will find little value in your abrupt assertion.  Consider adding demonstrations of your claim so future Readers can more easily appreciate your meaning.